# Make a Bootstrap button disabled, then enable it after some specific time

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button

I want to make a Bootstrap button disabled, but I want to enable it again after some time. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$('button').
  prop('disabled', true).
  setTimeout(function() { 
    $('button').prop('disabled', false)
  }, 3000);
```

Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` is not a method of a jQuery element. Change your code as follows:

```
$('button').prop('disabled', true);

setTimeout(function() { 
  $('button').prop('disabled', false)
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/w0nefkfo/

```js
$('button').prop('disabled', true);
setTimeout(function(){
 $('button').prop('disabled', false);
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

First disable the button like `$('button').attr("disabled", "disabled");` and use `setTimeout` and assign timeout value.

```js
$('button').attr("disabled", "disabled");
//or you can use #btn ref: $('#btn').attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
setTimeout(function() 
{
    $('button').removeAttr('disabled');
}, 3000);//3000 ms = 3 second.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Submit</button>
```

ref: [Window setTimeout() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('button').prop('disabled', true);
  setTimeout(function () {
      $('button').prop('disabled', false);
  }, 3000);
```